# Save/Cancel Inputs via Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm very new to Javascript and I need to make make a few input fields, where I can save and display information typed in or clear it with a cancel button and start over. Help please!!!

Comment: I guess your question only makes sense in your mind, which we don't have access to. Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: try to use google sometimes,it will help a lot.

Comment: http://www.newbie.org/JavaScript/

Answer (score 2):

In order to save the vale you can do something like this:

```
<input name="txtInput" type="text" maxlength="512" id="searchTxt" class="searchField"/>
```

Then in your JavaScript code:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("txtInput").value; // to save
document.getElementById("txtInput").value = ""; // to remove
```

Answer (score 2):

For clearing input fields use input type="reset" for reset button;

```
<input type='reset' value="Reset"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you will use HTML to create the field markup, but you can create the input fields on run time, if you want. I will tell you how to do it in both cases.

**HTML**

All input fields should be inside a FORM element, where you will specify the url (ACTION) to send the data.

```
<form action="data.php">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName" value="" placeholder="Type the name here..." />

    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" id="ageField" value="" placeholder="Please, tell us your age..." />

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

The **action** is where you set the destination url/file for your data.
Using the input type "submit", will add a button that will send you data without needs of use JS script. The "reset" type will reset the form, without JS.

**JS**

But as you are asking about JS code, you will need to know how to interact with the fields using JS script.

You can see an example using [native JS code](http://jsfiddle.net/ndevU/).

As you are learning, I strong recommend you first learn how to use pure JS, without any library like jQuery or Mootools. But only as reference, you can see the [same code using jQuery library](http://jsfiddle.net/GMt9B/)

You can learn better about the DOM elements, and how to manipulate them on the W3CSchools site . It is a good introductory documentation, take a look too, I'm sure it will help you.

I hope this can help you start.